# How to cbind a vector to a dataframe in python and keep the vector name as the name of the new column?

Tags: python, pandas

In R, `cbind(dataframe, new_column)` will return the original dataframe with an extra column called "new_column"

What is best practice for achieving this in Python (preferably using base or pandas)?

To make the question more concrete, suppose

```
web_stats = {'Day':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
             'Visitors':[43,34,65,56,29,76],
             'Bounce Rate':[65,67,78,65,45,52]}

df = pd.DataFrame(web_stats, columns = ['Day', 'Visitors', 'Bounce Rate'])
```

and

`new_column = [2,4,6,8,10,12]`

And that the final output should be

```
   Day  Visitors  Bounce Rate new_column
0    1        43           65     2
1    2        34           67     4
2    3        65           78     6
3    4        56           65     8
4    5        29           45     10
5    6        76           52     12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
web_stats['new_column'] = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
```